# Best way to export transactions from Rails App into QuickBooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, import, export, quickbooks

I have a rails app that takes care of all the bank transactions for us. Our accountant wants all those to be automatically imported into Quickbooks Pro (either online or desktop version). 
I've read about Web Connector and [Transaction Pro Importer](https://appcenter.intuit.com/transactionproimporter), but I feel like I don't have enough info to make a decision. I'd appreciate any advice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For QuickBooks for Windows:**

If you're a developer, and you're comfortable with developing with some SOAP components, the Web Connector will be a good direction to go for you.

There's some pretty decent Web Connector Ruby gems out there already:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+quickbooks+web+connector

If you're not a developer and/or don't want to develop something yourself, Transaction Pro makes things relatively easy to import/export.

**For QuickBooks Online:**

For SaaS applications, the QuickBooks Online APIs are very good. For non-SaaS applications, you have to use the qbXML gateway for QuickBooks Online, which is somewhat limiting sometimes. In your particular scenario (you're not a SaaS app allowing your customers to connect their QB files to your app) you'd be better off with QuickBooks for Windows.

Comment: I'm a beginner developer and would like to build something myself. Just had a chat with the accountant, looks like we're going to user QuickBooks Online version. All I need to do is grab the records from my app and import them into QB as Journal Entries. Would QuickBooks Online API do for this task?

Comment: That's definitely do-able. You can use the OSR for reference: http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html (check the "OE" checkbox, uncheck the "US" checkbox, and change it to 6.0 on the slider, and choose "JournalEntryAdd" from the drop-down). I don't have any sample Ruby code, but here's some HTTP example requests: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition#example_qbxml_for_online_edition  Register in DESKTOP mode, not HOSTED.

Comment: Thanks so much, Keith. That gives me something to start with!

Comment: Keith, sorry about so many questions. If we're going to host a 3 user version of QB on one of our servers, then would Web Connector be my solution? Thank you!

Comment: If you're using QuickBooks for Windows, then yes, use the Web Connector.

Comment: Keith, I feel a bit stuck again. I want to try to integrate with the Online version first. So I read in one of your SO-answers That Intuit doesn't support qbXML for QB-online anymore. I'm just confused about the steps I need to take. Do I need to register my app here - https://appreg.intuit.com/AddForm.aspx? All the documentation is full of abbreviations and seems too difficult to decipher for a person outside of the QB world. Could you please give me more direction on where to go next?

Comment: It's not *updated* anymore (no new features) but it *IS supported* (it does work). Until Intuit makes IPP available for non-SaaS apps, it's the only way you can integrate with QuickBooks Online. Follow the DESKTOP registration steps here: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition#connecting_with_the_desktop_model_of_communication

Comment: Why should I use the Desktop versions, when I want to get access to QB from my hosted rails App?

Comment: Regarding DESKTOP mode vs. HOSTED mode - they aren't *versions* per se, they are "security modes". The HOSTED security mode requires that you go through appreg, generate and have Intuit sign an SSL cert, have a separate SSL cert for your website, have correct rDNS entries, have an Intuit-approved SSL certificate, and accept the connection ticket for HTTP POST. The DESKTOP mode requires just that  you go through appreg. So, *either* will work... but DESKTOP mode is *much* easier to set up and get going with. Either will work just fine though.